# In Clojure (core.async) what's the difference between alts and alt?

Tags: clojure, core.async

I can't figure out the difference between:

```
alts!
```

and

```
alt!
```

in Clojure's [core.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`alts!` is a **function** that accepts a vector of channels to take from and/or channels with values to be put on them (in the form of doubleton vectors: `[c v]`). The vector may be dynamically constructed; the code calling `alts!` may not know how many channels it'll be choosing among (and indeed that number need not be constant across invocations).

`alt!` is a convenience **macro** which basically acts as a cross between `cond` and `alts!`. Here the number of "ports" (channels or channel+value pairs) must be known statically, but in practice this is quite often the case and the `cond`-like syntax is very clear.

`alt!` expands to a somewhat elaborate expression using `alts!`; apart from the syntactic convenience, it offers no extra functionality.