# Using alt! instead of alts! in Clojure

Tags: clojure, channel, core.async

I have some code that tries to send a message over a channel or times out after 150ms:

```
(let [[ret _] (alts!! [[work-chan parsed-body] (timeout 150)])]
  (cond ret :ok :else :error))
```

I was wondering what is the Clojure idiomatic way of sending messages over a channel, is alt!! the recommended way? If so, how exactly am I supposed to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Answered in:
[In clojure (core.async) what ‘s the difference of alts and alt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22085702/1594086)

The `alt!` have to be used in a `go` block, the `alt!!` function will lock the thread.

`alts!!` is like `alts!`, except takes will be made as if by `<!!`, and puts will be made as if by `>!!`, will block until completed, and not intended for use in `(go ...)` blocks.

Documentation: https://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/alt!!

Comment: Would you mind rewriting my timeout code using alt! ? Thank you in advance.