# how to understand alt in clojure core.async

Tags: clojure, core.async

I have read the following document and the example, but still doesn't get what it really means. I understand alts!!, but not alt!!.Anybody show an example easy to understand?

https://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/alt!!

I have also ready the following link

[In Clojure (core.async) what's the difference between alts and alt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085497/in-clojure-core-async-whats-the-difference-between-alts-and-alt)

update: The example is in the doc is:

```
(alt!
  [c t] ([val ch] (foo ch val))
  x ([v] v)
  [[out val]] :wrote
  :default 42)
```

for the second line of

```
[c t] ([val ch] (foo ch val))
```

channel-op of [c t] means a channel c and an value t:  put value t on channel c.
result-expr of ([val ch] (foo ch val)) means bidding [val ch] for the operation, but since it's a list, [val ch] should be evaluate as a function, and (foo ch val) will be as the parameter passed to function of [val ch]. but what does it mean for function of [val ch] with parameter of (foo ch val) ?

Comment: What part do you not understand?

Comment: I think you're slightly off in your interpretation of the second line. `[c t]` is a vector of ports.  `[val ch]` is a binding (as you said).  `ch` is the channel that could be taken from; and `val` is the value taken .  Function `foo` is then evaluated using that binding.  See https://gist.github.com/konacaret/d1f5c19cfbe46d3b97a3 for a simple example of this.

Comment: That's very much for the example, it's very clear. Better to put it on the official doc :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [c t] ([val ch] (foo ch val))

There are some cases where a list doesn't mean "evaluate as a function". For example:

```
(ns com.foo.bar
  (:require …))
```

In the above code, there is no function called `:require` being called.

Another example of lists being used for something other than function application is `letfn`:

```
(letfn [(foo [x] (+ (bar 1) x))
        (bar [x] (+ 2 x))]
  (+ (foo 5) (bar 7)))
```

As you can see above, `letfn` has two lists, one starting with the symbol `foo`, and one starting with the symbol `bar`, and neither of these lists is a traditional function call. Instead, `letfn` is *defining* two new functions, one with the name `foo`, and the other with the name `bar`. The rest of the expression is treated as a "body" in which to use those functions.

> but what does it mean for function of [val ch] with parameter of (foo ch val) ?

Similar to `letfn`, `alt` *defines* a value named `val` and a channel named `ch`, and then the rest of the expression (`(foo ch val)`) is treated as a "body" in which to use those two names.

## Explanation of `alt!/alt!!`:

I find it easiest to think of `alt!` and `alt!!` as being somewhat like `cond`, except instead of testing conditions to choose a body to execute, it waits on channels to choose a body to execute. Each clause consists of two parts, just like `cond` – the first part (the **"channel op"**) is used to specify a channel that `alt!` should wait on, and the second part (the **"result expr"**) specifies what should happen if that channel delivers a value first.

Since you probably want to access the value delivered by the channel *or* the channel itself when this happens, the **result expr** gives you the opportunity to bind both the value and the channel to symbols, and a body of code to execute with those bindings. Thus, the following clause…

```
[c t]
([val ch]
  (foo ch val))
```

…means:

> One of the channel operations that this call to `alt!` should block on is an attempt to *take* from either of two channels, `c` or `t`. If either of those send a value before any other **channel op** in this call to `alt!`, then execute `(foo ch val)` with `val` bound to the value taken from the channel that first delivered a value, and with `ch` bound to the channel that delivered `val` (which will be either `c` or `t`).

and the following clause…

```
[[out input-val]]
([val ch]
  (bar ch val))
```

…means:

> One of the channel operations that this call to `alt!` should block on is an attempt to *put* `input-val` onto a channel called `out`. If that succeeds before any other **channel op** in this call to `alt!`, then execute `(bar ch val)` with `val` bound to `input-val` and `ch` bound to `out` (the channel that successfully received the value).

Altogether, these two clauses would be written as:

```
(alt!
  [c t]        ; "Takes" can be a single channel instead of vectors.
  ([val ch]
    (foo ch val))

  [[out input-val]] ; "Puts" must be nested vectors.
  ([val ch]
    (bar ch val)))
```

Comment: Thanks erikprice, great explanation.  One quesiont of [c t], are both c and t channel like  konacaret show https://gist.github.com/konacaret/d1f5c19cfbe46d3b97a3? I read again the doc, if it's [[c t]], then c is a putting channel, and t is the value to put. If it's simply [c t], then both should be channel, am I right?

Comment: @DanielWu yes, you are right. I mistook the vector to indicate a "put" operation, but "put" requires nested vectors as you describe, and non-nested vectors are simply multiple channels to "take" from. I have updated the answer to reflect the correction so that it shows by "takes" and "puts".